# SQL join query to fetch the data items based on max dDateEffective and other conditions

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to result based on joining these 4 tables,

Table: DataItem

```
iDataItemID iDataTypeID iEmployeeID 
275599  8   1
```

Table: DataItemStatus

i
    iDataStatusID   iDataItemID iDataItemStatusID (Foreign key from RefDataItemStatus)  dDateEffective
    1   275599  1   22/07/2018
    2   275599  4   21/07/2018
    3   275599  1   20/07/2018

Table: RefDataItemStatus

```
iDataItemStatusID   sDataItemStatus     
5   Terminal        
4   Failed      
3   Processed       
2   Processing      
1   Submitted
```

Table: RefDataType

```
iDataTypeID sDataType       
8   EmployeeAgreement
```

I need to fetch the data items on a particular dataItemStatusID and iDataTypeID.

I'm able to achieve this by the following query,

```
DECLARE @DataItemCurrentStatusID INT = 1
DECLARE @DataTypeID INT = 8



Select DataItem.iDataItemID, 
DataItem.iDataTypeID,
DataItemStatus.iDataItemCurrentStatusID,
DataItemStatus.iDataItemStatusID  
from DataItem 
INNER JOIN DataItemStatus ON 
DataItemStatus.iDataItemID = 
DataItem.iDataItemID 
INNER JOIN ORefDataItemStatus ON 
DataItemStatus.iDataItemStatusID = 
RefDataItemStatus.iDataItemStatusID
AND DataItemStatus.iDataItemCurrentStatusID = @DataItemCurrentStatusID AND 
DataItem.iDataTypeID = @DataTypeID
```

The issue is there could multiple data items mapped with the same status in DataItemStatus table. I need to fetch the dataItem, only if the dDateEffective value is max in DataItemStatus table for that dataItem.

Like in the below example as in the snapshot,

If i want to fetch the dataItems in failed state (i.e iDataTypeID = 4), I dont want to get the iDataItemID = 275599 in the result, bcoz there is an update to that iDataItemID with a new status again on 22/07/2018

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ8DB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved,

```
Select DI.iDataItemID, 
DI.iDataTypeID,
DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID,
DIS.iDataItemStatusID  
from DataItem DI
INNER JOIN DataItemStatus DIS ON DIS.iDataItemID = DI.iDataItemID 
INNER JOIN RefDataItemStatus ON DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID = 
RefDataItemStatus.iDataItemStatusID
AND DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID = 1 AND DI.iDataTypeID = 8 and DIS.dDateEffective IN 
(
SELECT Max(dDateEffective) FROM OT_BackendUpdate_DataItemStatus Where 
OT_BackendUpdate_DataItemStatus.iDataItemID = DI.iDataItemID
)
```